# Can we have a terminal that we can write like a text editor?

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, text-editor

Something that (for me) doesn't make sense is that terminals don't act like other text areas, like when we write on a text editor or on your browser. Features like copy and paste, select text, etc, work differently in a terminal.

Is it possible to run a terminal that works like a normal text editor, that just runs the command we wrote when we press some key?

##### Edit

To make myself clearer, what I am asking is exact what [@Ghos3t pointed out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1415694/can-we-have-a-terminal-that-we-can-write-like-a-text-editor#comment2495888_1415694) in the comments:

> I think everyone is missing the meaning of what OP is asking, he doesn't want a terminal text editor like nano, he's talking about the text prompt where we type terminal commands, and why that does not follow the conventions like any normal text box, such as having the option to hit Ctrl/Cmd + A to select an entire line and hit backspace to delete it instead of having to backspace one char at a time, or the fact that normal copy and paste commands don't work in some terminals etc. Why can't the terminal text prompt just work like the VSCode command palate.

Can we have a terminal that strictly follows the same patterns as the text editors? And why terminals follow different patterns than text areas?

Comment: People have created loads of CLI shells that achieved something they felt was worthwhile where they acted like other programs, but in almost all cases the creations saw little use by others, and were soon dropped by the initial creator themselves (*as they decided the negatives were too costly; or just moved onto other newer projects*). The shell can do whatever it's creator wants and programs it to do.

Comment: What is it are you asking? It seems like you're asking why terminal apps and shells are not text editors. Your terminal app and the shell are not text editors. There are some terminal based text editors though, like vim and nano. At the end of your question it seems like what you're really asking is how to run commands that you've typed into the terminal. In every terminal app and shell I'm familiar with, you use the `Enter` key. Can you be more specific about what it is you are asking? Keep in mind that questions seeking discussion or opinions are off-topic here.

Comment: Digital Ocean has a good tutorial aimed at people with no knowledge of terminal emulators. It explains, in general, what it's for, and how it works. You may want to check that out: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-the-linux-terminal

Comment: In bash, if you press `ctrl-x, ctrl-e`, by default it opens up the current line in whatever editor is set as `$EDITOR`, you can edit the command there, and when you save and exit, it runs the command. It's possible to do something similar in zsh.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking about. You can write in any terminal emulator, you can copy and paste text there, etc. So what is the problem? Are you asking about how to use a terminal emulator properly? A text editor and a terminal emulator are completely different things.

Comment: I think everyone is missing the meaning of what OP is asking, he doesn't want a terminal text editor like nano, he's talking about the text prompt where we type terminal commands, and why that does not follow the conventions like any normal text box, such as having the option to hit Ctrl/Cmd + A to select an entire line and hit backspace to delete it instead of having to backspace one char at a time, or the fact that normal copy and paste commands don't work in some terminals etc. Why can't the terminal text prompt just work like the VSCode command palate.

Comment: I actually have a valid suggestion for the OP, if the question gets reopened. 

Comment: The premise seems flawed: The terminal commands are much older than the browsers and word processors and other applications. Those newer applications are the ones that broke the standards. There were a lot of complaints about this back in the 1980s and early 1990s, but Apple and Microsoft ignored them so now we have different command sets. Neither is "correct", neither is "wrong".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because terminals are in fact terminal emulators. They emulate hardware that are **line based**. and because they come from a very distant past. First terminals were no smarter that a typewriter.

Nowadays, we have screens that can be redrwawn at will. In a text editor, you can click anywhere to set the insertion cursor wherever you want, but back in the older days, there was no screen. There was just a printer and a keyboard. Eventually, you can erase the last character you've typed, or kill the whole line, but not much.

Over time, terminals (the hardware one) became more capable and smarter, and eventually the mythical VT100 came to existence. terminal emulators that we use today emulate a VT100, more or less, with some additions (for example, current terminal emulators correctly handle national char : european languages and their weird symbols (ç Æ, ñ, Å...), greek, hebrew, asian languages, in fact most unicode symbols)

Their set of commands existed before graphical UI existed. In a terminal, Control-C is caught by the terminal driver and mapped to a signal that kindly ask the current process to terminate. This is history. Also note that in a terminal, you don't really edit text (not counting the fact that you can run editors in full screen mode), you type a letter, this letter is sent to the computer, the computer sends back the letter and this letter is thus printed on screen. When you hit enter, the remote computer executes the command and you just receive output.

Why didn' we invent terminals where we can edit like in any other text window ? Because it does not make sense. A terminal is sequential : logically we type in sequence a command and get an answer. Also because of how it works. each character is sent and when (if) it comes back, it is printed on screen. How does a mouse cursor, mobile insertion cursor fits in this model ?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal

Comment: Actually, the main reason seems to be the collision of ctrl-Shortcuts. The MacOS terminal proves that there is no other conflict: You can use it as any other terminal, but additionally can copy&paste, mark with mouse, drag and drop and so on. Why not? ctrl-c  sends the signal while command-c copies. No conflicts.

Comment: Actually, there were full-screen terminals, that were operated in quite an unusual way, by sending whole screens of characters to the machine (instead of Enter key you used something like Screen key) and receiving whole screens back. It was a "3270" family of terminals that worked with IBM mainframes. There is terminal emulation software for this kind of terminal, but I doubt that any *nix-like system supports them.

Answer (score 6):

Normally, Bash will be in `emacs` mode. If this is the case (and as indicated by [the comment from @frabjous](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1415694/can-we-have-a-terminal-that-we-can-write-like-a-text-editor/1458321#comment2461691_1415694)), you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> to enter "text editor mode". This can be done from either *a blank command* line, or by editing *an existing command* that has already been typed.

Now you can enter all your commands in the text editor, and when you exit, each line will be executed as a command - just as if it was a Bash script.

The editor will default to `vim`. To set another editor (in this case `nano`), set the environment variable `EDITOR`, by adding this in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
export EDITOR=nano
```

#### IMPORTANT WARNING

Another post on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85393/406012) has an important warning for this feature, by the user marlar:

> Be very careful with this feature. If you cancel the edit, the
> original command line will be immediately executed. So if you are
> editing `rm -rf /` and invoke the editor and realize you are into
> something dangerous and thus cancel the edit, your rootfs will be
> deleted without further questions asked.

This isn't an issue if you start with a blank command, but if you start with an existing command that might be destructive, **ALWAYS** clear the file and save before exiting the editor.

There's a possible workaround [in this Super User answer](https://superuser.com/a/1601690/1210833).  Also note that this is primarily a Bash issue.  Zsh and Fish will only paste the command into the prompt, but not execute it.

##### Tip for advanced users

You might find yourself in a situation (like me) where the keybinding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> is already in use by an application that catches it before it reaches Bash *(this could be your terminal emulater, a multiplexer like `tmux` etc.)*.

In this case, you could rebind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to another key combination. This can be done by adding this line in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
bind '"\C-f":"\C-x"'
```

In this example, a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> sequence is sent to Bash when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> is pressed. So now you have remapped the hardcoded keybinding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> *(it's actually defined in the Readline library used by Bash)*.

Comment: You could also just `set -o vi` in bash and then hit <ESC> to edit the command line with a good subset of vi commands: https://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/vi-mode-in-bash/

Answer (score 2):

I have a suggestion that doesn't do exactly what you ask, but does something similar in a more flexible way.

You could create your own script that launches a text editor where you can type in a "script" (just commands), and when you exit and save, the commands are executed.

For starters, create the following script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

filepath="/dev/shm"

# Give a unique filename
date=$(date '+%Y%m%d-%H%M%S')

# Open your favorite editor ('nano' by default)
nano "$filepath/$date"

# Only execute if file is acatually written
if [[ -f "$filepath/$date" ]]
then

  # Insert shebang for interpreter ('/bin/bash' by default)
  sed -i '1i#!/bin/bash\' "$filepath/$date"

  # Make file executable
  chmod +x "$filepath/$date"

  # Run the script you just made
  "$filepath/$date"

  # Delete the script again (comment out if you want to preserve the history)
  # rm "$filepath/$date"

fi
```

Now save this script as `run-commands`, put it somewhere in your `PATH` and make it executable (`chmod +x ./run-commands`).

In addition, you could edit your `.bash_aliases` and add the following:

```
alias rc='run-commands'
bind -x '"\C-r":run-commands'
```

Now, this is how it works:

- If you type either `rc` or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, you'll now open a text editor (`nano` is the default).
- Here you can type in your commands line by line - as you would in any other shell script.
- When you exit the editor (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> by default), the script is created, made executable and run!
- Created commands (scripts) are located in `/dev/shm`, which is a default ramdisk provided by Ubuntu. This is cleared on reboot (which makes sense to me).

This has some pros and cons compared to your question.

*Pros:*

- The solution is easier to implement and more flexible than replacing your entire shell with something that is harder to maintain.
- You don't loose any existing functionality, but instead only adds additional functionality when you want it.
- You can freely customize which editor (`nano` by default) and shell (`/bin/bash` by default) you want to use by default.
- The functionality of the script can easily be expanded with history function, editing of previous commands, support for more interpreters etc. *(I might take a look at this if I have the time someday.)*

*Cons:*

- You have to activate a key combination (or run `rc`) to start the special "script mode" invoked by this script.
- You have to save the script with the usual key combination of the text editor before the commands can be run.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy or paste text, or select text! lxterminal is an option. We don't understand your question. If you want it to runs the command you write when you press some key, You can create a script file, a .sh file, then execute the script, choosing to open it with the terminal and that's all, you just click mouse once! to do that thing you want it to do. There are more options out there to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a text editor like **nano** to write text in your terminal

simply type in your terminal this command:

```
nano mynewfile
```

also you can use [**YuranPad**](https://sourceforge.net/projects/yuranpad/) a graphical text edit to write

```
yuranpad mynewfile
```

Answer (score 0):

We have one text editor named as gedit but it won't work in terminal it will give you feels like notepad in windows and open a new pop-up window but if you're really interested to work on terminal you should have to choose vim editor nano editor.
Type following to open gedit editor

```
gedit filename.txt
```

To get started with vim editor you should install it using apt package manager by following command

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

Then type

```
vimtutor
```

And to learn nano text editor just follow the command which will be shown to you in terminal
For example:-
ctrl + s for save
ctrl + w for exit.